# Bound on the first-order partial derivative

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative

Suppose $f(t,s):[0,T] \times [0,\infty)$ has at-most quadratic growth w.r.t $s$, uniformly w.r.t $t$. What sort of growth condition can we impose on $\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}$?

Comment: None. $f(s) = \sin(h(s))$ is bounded, but $f'(s) = h'(s)\sin(h(s))$ can grow arbitrary large – choose $h(x) = x^2$ or $h(x) = e^{e^x}$ or ...

Comment: @MartinR so unless we know more about $f$, such as perhaps its explicit form, we can't establish anything?

Comment: No. You can bound $f$ in terms of $f'$ (via the mean-value theorem) but not the other way around.